# Installing docker hangs at "setting up docker-engine" on ubuntu xenial

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker

I'm trying to install docker on ubuntu xenial and am following this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/. So far it's gone without a hitch except for there apparently not being a linux-image-extra for my kernel version (4.6.0-040600-generic). The tutorial said that that wasn't required, though, so I figured it wasn't completely necessary.

I got to the point of running `sudo apt-get install docker-engine`, and the install is hanging on `Setting up docker-engine (1.11.2-0~xenial) ...`. I've looked at `top` and it's not using any cpu, so I don't think it's actually doing anything. I ended up restarting my computer, getting rid of the partly installed package with some combination of dpkg -r, apt-get --purge remove, and maybe some other related stuff that I've forgotten about, and I tried installing it again. It hung the same way.

How can I install this successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the service can't be started. You can interrupt the apt command by doing `systemctl restart docker` and then just following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37640824/287130

Comment: For me `systemctl restart docker` hangs, too.

Comment: @SebastianBarth same here and systemctl stop docker then worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try `systemctl stop docker.service`.  That did it for me.  Trying to restart it lead to a hang.